# Unable to do S3 Cross region replication with KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I'm tring to replicate objects from us-west-2 to us-east-2 in s3 using cross region replication.
i have tried two methods.

Method 1:
source bucket with KMS key 1 in us-west-2.
Destination bucket with KMS key 2 in us-east-2

i have created replication configuration from source bucket to replicate SSE-KMS encrypted object.but replication gets failed.i used aws generated IAM policy for it.

Method 2:(using multi-region key and replica)
source bucket with KMS master key in us-west-2.
Destination bucket with KMS replica key in us-east-2

same replicaiton configuration process

when i delete the obect in source bucket ,delete marker appears in destination but but object is not getting replicated

need a help in pointing out me in right direction
thanks

i have tried all the steps and blogs online still no solution for the problem i'm facing